# How is test sharding supposed to work?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am working with android espresso. I have various "types" of instrumentation tests placed in packages. For example "mypackage.loginScreenTests", "mypackage.paymentScreenTests", "mypackage.registerScreenTests" etc.

And so far I am running all of them at once. Tests tend to affect each other what is leading to malfunctioning despite the fact if I run only for example loginScreenTests they work.

From what I read from there:
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#ajur-sharding

I could create 3 shards and place each group of tests on different shard, then run them by id - like first 0, then 1, then 2. But I can't find any example and documentation feels a bit unclear to me.

I know how to run test with shard id, but I don't know how to divide tests located in *.java files into shards. Could someone explain that to me?